# Create my own fgets() function using read(fd, buf, sz)

Tags: c, file, readline, fgets, fgetc

I am trying to build my own lineread method to read a file line by line using a filedes, a buffer and a size parameter. My reasoning is that I can read the file using 1 as my size to go through every character and check if it is the end of the line. If it's not it has to keep reading and if it is it stops and sent the result to the main function. But my problem is that I can't seem to get the file right.
Here is the code:

read_file.c:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "lineread.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: read_file filename\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    ssize_t read_sz;
    unsigned long counter = 0;

    while (true) {
        char buf[64] = { 0 };
        read_sz = lineread(fd, buf, 63);
        if (read_sz <= 0) {
            break;
        }
        printf("Read %lu, bytes: %zu | %s\n", counter, read_sz, buf);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

lineread.c:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
ssize_t lineread(int fd, char *buf, size_t sz)
{
    while(*buf != '\n') {
        if(*buf == '\0'){
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            read(fd, buf, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

lineread.h:

```
#ifndef _LINEREAD_H_
#define _LINEREAD_H_

#include <sys/types.h>

ssize_t lineread(int fd, char *buf, size_t sz);

#endif
```

Comment: When lineread is called the first time, what is *buf going to be (inside lineread)? What does lineread return? After you have read one byte with read(), where does buf point?

Comment: I suppose *buf is going to be the very first character of the file. lineread should return a 1 or a 0 depending on if the line has been read. And buf is suppose to point to the next character after reading the first one right?

Comment: `I suppose *buf is going to be the very first character of the file` no, `*buf` is not initialized, with `read` you read from file.

Comment: Unless you have a need to use `read`, you can use `getc` or `fgetc` to the same end with the benefit of the file-stream interface.

Comment: I absolutely need to use read :/ ahah

Comment: Here is a `fgetc` implementation you can pull ideas from and replace with `read` - [fgetc-line](https://paste.opensuse.org/90444817) (link good for 30 days)

Comment: Thank you! I will look into it right now